# Parse.com - can't find build.gradle file

Tags: android, parse-platform

ParseStarterProject is really, really frustrating. I tried to add Google Play services to compile in build.gradle and it don't wanted to sync. Then I removed it to make it work again, but it showed that there is settings.gradle file missing. When I tried to create it by myself - it fails to save it... Now I have `Failed to resolve: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0` and I don't know what to do with it. I want to make a new project from scratch and copy my code, but seems like it's more complicated than just copy & paste.

ParseStarterProject.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
  masterKey YOUR_MASTER_KEY

  // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

Comment: Probably not helpful, but: I had that `Failed to resolve: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0` -- but I just hit Build in Android Studio and it resolved it.

Comment: I have now same problem, but with `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0`...

Comment: This many not help but, update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to use the latest version `1.2.3` -- previous versions were fairly buggy.  Also, have you tried using gradle from the command-line? Try `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug` (the --debug flag outputs more information that may help)